# How to display react website logged user details in another wordpress website

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, authentication, web, logging

I have two sites, one is developed in react.js and another is in wordpress. Wordpress will be the main site and react will be its sub domain site. There will be one login page in react site, anyone logged in react site and then coming to main wordpress site in same browser need to simply show that react logged in user name in wordpress menu header.

How we make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, you can simply set a cookie on the subdomain (=react site) that you can access on the main domain (=wordpress site)
[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)